# Two mysql_fetch_array statements in

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, fetch

Is there any reason why I couldn't include two mysql_fetch_array statements working on two different mysql query results in one while loop?

The reason is I have two query results from a mysql database each containing two columns as follows:

```
Query 1: Date,     Value 1                 
Query 2: Date,     Value 2
```

Dates in each query are always week ending dates at regular intervals of 1 week ordered in ascending order.  However they may start and finish at different dates for either query result.

I want to build arrays to return to the calling web page of date, value  1 and value 2 only where both values 1 and 2 are available over the same period.

I have included an if / else block that compares the first date in each query and sets a pointer using mysql_data_seek for which ever result set has the earliest start date to ensure it is advanced to the date corresponding to the first available date in the other record set.

Because the last available date may also be different, I thought that to ensure the arrays to be returned are both of the same length (therefore truncating whichever result has the more recent data to the last available date of the other result), I thought that I could iterate through both query results as follows:

```
$ReturnDate = array();
$ReturnValue1 = array();
$ReturnValue2 = array();

$i=0;
while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($res_Query1,MYSQL_NUM) && $row2=mysql_fetch_array($res_Query2,MYSQL_NUM)) { 
        $ReturnDate[$i]= $row1[0];
        $ReturnValue1[$i] = (float)$row1[1];
        $ReturnValue2[$i] = (float)$row2[1];
        $i++;
}
```

However, the second return value array always returns a sequence of zeros.  Is the above code valid?

Many thanks

Comment: May Query1 and Query2 have two different number of lines? Or do they necessary have the same number of line? Does column Date is necessary a date of end of week? What is a end of such a week (Monday? Sunday?). And is it correct to say that the column Date represents a period of 1 week starting from (Date-6) and going up to (Date) ?

Comment: Yes - either query represents a series of data covering different time-spans but which would necessarily overlap at some point.

Comment: Yes - column date holds a series of dates all of which are a week ending date, in the case of both queries it would be a sunday at 23:59. however, records for each query span a different number of weeks.  The value is a value representing consumption over the course of the week ending on that date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `&&` to `and`. No, I'm not kidding.

`&&` has higher priopity then `=` (but `and` not) so

`$a = foo() && $b = bar()` would be really `$a = (foo() && ($b = bar()))`

Comment: Right @Emmerman, this is actually a bug in the code of @nortyrich.

Comment: Nevertheless, it seems to me that this fix is not enough to perform the task your expecting. With the @Emmerman fix, the code still cannot deal correctly with queries that return different numbers of records, or same weeks that do not appear in the same row number.

Comment: This error drove me crazy for a couple of hours. I didn't know `&&` and `and` had different priorities, so thank you Emmerman for telling this. My solution at the time was to add parenthesis: `if (($a = foo()) && ($b = bar())) { ... }`